# Pandas.DataFrame.GroupBy.agg, independent column needed in aggregation function. How to get it into agg?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame object with a two-level MultiIndex. Furthermore it obviously contains a number of additional columns (e.g. 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'). I want to execute some aggregation function on the individual multi indices in the DataFrame on each individual column from a subset of the available columns (say, 'C', 'D', 'E'). For this purpose I select only the subset of columns, use GroupBy to group the thus sliced data frame by `levels=[0,1]` and execute `agg` with a dictionary configuring the aggregation function for each of the selected columns from the mentioned subset.

```py
df[['C', 'D', 'E']].groupby(level=[0, 1]).agg({'C': aggfunc, 'D': aggfunc, 'E': aggfunc})
```

My problem now is that in addition to the currently aggregated column that is handed into the aggregation function, I need a second column, e.g. 'B', in the aggregation function. So it's basically an aggregation of two columns, one of ['C', 'D', 'E'] plus 'B'.

What I could do is replacing `aggfunc` with a closure that knows 'B'. Is that the only way? Or is there a way to tell Pandas to also hand 'B' into the aggregation function in addition to 'C', 'D', 'E'?

### Example notebook

I've created a Jupyter Notebook to generate example data. In the example, you can see the columns `serial` and `turn` which form the MultiIndex, and the column `milage` which is the independent column that I need in the aggregation function in addition to the columns `m1` to `m4` each. So in the function I need `m<n>` (whichever is currently processed) plus `milage`. Since `milage` is a float value too I cannot use it as index.

The notebook can be found here: https://github.com/HWiese1980/public_notebooks/blob/master/example.ipynb

Comment: so need `df[['C', 'D', 'E']].reset_index().groupby(['A','B']).agg({'B': aggfunc, 'C': aggfunc, 'D': aggfunc, 'E': aggfunc})` ?

Comment: Is possible some sample data?

Comment: Real sample data is difficult because of NDA. That's why I resorted to 'A', 'B', 'C'. I need to keep the existing MultiIndex for grouping by it, or don't I?

Comment: Hard question, but `df[['C', 'D', 'E']].reset_index().groupby(['A','B']).agg({ 'C': aggfunc, 'D': aggfunc, 'E': aggfunc})` vs `df[['C', 'D', 'E']].groupby(level=[0, 1]).agg({'C': aggfunc, 'D': aggfunc, 'E': aggfunc})` should working same.

Comment: Oh, and the independent column 'B' is a float. So I cannot group by it because then I'd only get a single row in the aggregation function. However, I need all values of 'B' which correspond to the currently processed MultiIndex.

Comment: Really hard without data.  Antother way should be  create column `B1` from `Multiindex` and `MultiIndex` is not changed... But not sure if need it.

Comment: Maybe also a bit misleadingly worded: 'A' and 'B' neither are part of the MultiIndex. The MultiIndex is made from two additional columns that I missed mentioning. 'A' is just an example column that I don't need for aggregation. I mentioned it because I wanted to point out that there are other columns unrelated to the actual problem.

Comment: I'll see if I can come up with a sample closer to reality, without disclosing actual customer data.

Comment: i dont need customer data, be free change `df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('aaabbb'),
         'B':[4.3,5,4.3,5,5,4.3],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4]
}).set_index(['A','B'])`

Comment: I've added a notebook that can generate example data

Comment: hmmm, why `Since milage is a float value too I cannot use it as index.` ?

Comment: Your latest comment, @jezrael, made me rethink my statement and, yes, I can use it as additional index, but I must not group by it. It works now, by adding `milage` as index and removing it from the index again in the aggregation function. Thank you! You can formulate it as answer, then I can accept it.

Comment: Yop, working for solution without it, but is crazy, add both solutions.

Comment: Awesome. Yes, it feels a bit like abusing index for this purpose and I assume that it breaks many optimizations of Pandas. Would love to see a solution without abusing index.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `agg` function `'see'` only processing columns, not another ones.

So it is possible, but not performant, because is necessary filtering per groups:

```
np.random.seed(2020)
cols = ["serial", "turn", "milage", "m1", "m2", "m3", "m4"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols).set_index("serial", "turn")

serials = ["11111", "11222", "12345"]

data = []
end = 0.0
for s in serials:
    for t in range(np.random.randint(6)):
        start = end + np.random.rand() * 1000.
        end = start + np.random.rand() * 1000.
        run_point_count = np.random.randint(high=10, low=5)
        milages = np.linspace(start, end, run_point_count)
        for entry in range(run_point_count):
            d = np.hstack((np.array([s, t]), [milages[entry]], np.random.rand(4)))
            _df = {}
            for i, c in enumerate(cols): 
                _df[c] = d[i]
            data.append(_df)

df_out = df.append(data, ignore_index=True, sort=True).set_index(["serial", "turn"])
df_out = df_out.astype(float)
#print (df_out)
```

---

```
def aggfunc(x):
    return x.sum() + df_out.loc[x.index, "milage"].mean()

#need unique MultiIndex
df_out = df_out.set_index(df_out.groupby(level=[0, 1]).cumcount(), append=True)
df = (df_out.groupby(level=[0, 1])
           .agg({'m1': aggfunc, 'm2': aggfunc, 'm3': aggfunc, 'm4': aggfunc}))
print (df)
                      m1           m2           m3           m4
serial turn                                                    
12345  0      735.612167   734.425345   733.988098   736.534878
       1     1763.739719  1762.587273  1763.196721  1763.929828
       2     2582.773092  2583.585509  2582.582403  2582.121202
```

Second solution is with convert column to `FloatIndex`:

```
def aggfunc(x):
    return x.sum() + np.mean(x.index.get_level_values(3))


df = (df_out.set_index('milage', append=True)
           .groupby(level=[0, 1])
           .agg({'m1': aggfunc, 'm2': aggfunc, 'm3': aggfunc, 'm4': aggfunc}))
print (df)
                      m1           m2           m3           m4
serial turn                                                    
12345  0      735.612167   734.425345   733.988098   736.534878
       1     1763.739719  1762.587273  1763.196721  1763.929828
       2     2582.773092  2583.585509  2582.582403  2582.121202
```

EDIT:

If possible use some function working with all column of `DataFrame` use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def f(x):
       return x[['m1','m2','m3','m4']].sum() + x['milage'].mean()

df = df_out.groupby(level=[0, 1]).apply(f)
print (df)
                      m1           m2           m3           m4
serial turn                                                    
12345  0      735.612167   734.425345   733.988098   736.534878
       1     1763.739719  1762.587273  1763.196721  1763.929828
       2     2582.773092  2583.585509  2582.582403  2582.121202
```